# How can I get input using an array and store in the variable in my main class from my record.h class?

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, input

How can I get input and store it into each variable I defined in the Record.h file?

I was trying to do this with an array to streamline it, but I can't figure out how to do that. I have tried for hours to figure this out. I am not sure if it is even possible.

This is the assignment I am working on to give a understanding

> For this activity, you will create an address book console program
>   that 
>    1. Uses a basic array in the main program to hold multiple Record class objects.
>    2. A Record class is to be constructed with the following member variables Record number, first name, last name, age, and telephone number.
>
> 3.The Record class must have a custom constructor that initializes the member variables.
>
> 4.The Record class declaration is to be separated from the Record class implementation and these are to be placed in .h and .cpp files
>   respectively.
>
> 5.The program should have a perpetual menu that allows a choice of:
>
> > a. Input information into an record, **(This is my problem)**
> >
> > b. Display all information in all records, and
> >
> > c. Exit the program.
>
> 6.The program should hold 10 records at the minimum.
>
> 7.Test output with 0 people input, 5 people input and 10 people input before submitting the .cpp and .h files for this assignment.

**Main.cpp**

```
//
//  Main.cpp
//
//
//  Created by Jake Huckestein on 1/3/19.
//
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "Record.h"
using namespace std;
int choice;
int main()
{

    do {
        cout << ("Menu") << endl;
        cout << ("1.Input information into an record.") << endl;
        cout << ("2.Display all information in all records.") << endl;
        cout << ("3.Exit the program") << endl;
        cout << ("Please enter your choice:") << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
            {
                std::string fnameIN,lnameIN,idIN,telephoneIN,ageIN;

                Record Item[10];

                for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
                {
                    cout <<("Employee ID:")<<endl;
                    cin >> Item;
                }

                break;
            }
            case 2:

                for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
                {
                    cout << Item[i].getemployeeID(idIN) << endl;
                }
                getchar();

                break;
            case 3:
                return 0;
                break;
        }

    } while (choice != 0);
}
```

**Record.cpp**

```
//
//  Record.cpp
//  Jake
//
//  Created by Jake Huckestein on 1/3/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Jake Huckestein. All rights reserved.
//


#include "Record.h"

#include <string>

void Record::setemployeeID (string idIn)
{
    employeeID = idIn;
}
void Record::setfirstName (string fnameIn)
{
    firstName = fnameIn;
}
void Record::setlastName (string lnameIn)
{
    lastName = lnameIn;
}
void Record::settelephone (string phoneIn)
{
    telephone = phoneIn;
}
void Record::setage (string ageIn)
{
    age = ageIn;
}
//get functions
string Record::getemployeeID()
{
    return employeeID;
}
string Record::getfirstName()
{
    return firstName;
}
string Record::getlastName()
{
    return lastName;
}
string Record::gettelephone()
{
    return telephone;
}
string Record::getage()
{
    return age;
}
```

**Record.h**

```
//Author: Created by Jake Huckestein on 1/3/19.Date:
//FileName: Record.h
//Purpose: Creates an Record Class.
//Input: Data values input via set functions and assigned to member
vars.
//Output: Data values retrieved by get functions and returned to
caller.Exceptions:

#ifndef Record_h
#define Record_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Record
{
private:
    string employeeID;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string telephone;
    string age;

public:
    Record()
    {
    }

    Record(string idIn) :employeeID(idIn)
    {
    }

    Record(string idIn, string fnameIn, string lnameIn)
        :employeeID(idIn),firstName(fnameIn),lastName(lnameIn)
    {
    }
    Record(string idIN, string fnameIN, string lnameIN, string telephoneIN)
        :employeeID(idIN),firstName(fnameIN),
    lastName(lnameIn),telephone(telephoneIN)
    {
    }

    Record(string idIn, string fnameIn, string 
    lnameIn,stringtelephoneIn, string ageIn)
        :employeeID(idIn),firstName(fnameIn),
    lastName(lnameIn),telephone(telephoneIn),age(ageIn)
    {
        if (telephoneIn.length() == 12
            && telephoneIn.at(3) == '-'
            && telephoneIn.at(7) == '-')
        {
            telephone = telephoneIn;
        }
        else
        {
            telephone = "000-000-0000";
        }
    }
    void setemployeeID (string idIn);

    void setfirstName (string fnameIn);

    void setlastName (string lnameIn);

    void settelephone (string phoneIn);

    void setage (string ageIn);

    string getemployeeID();

    string getfirstName();

    string getlastName();

    string gettelephone();

    string getage();

};
#endif /* Record_hpp */
```

**Code I have tried in main.cpp no particular order**

```
Record Employee1("Ab123","Jake","Jones","205-612-5519","30");
Record Employee2("Ab124","Jakey","Jonesy","205-612-5518","31");
Record Employee3("Ab125","Jake","Jones","205-612-5519","30");
Record Employee4("Ab126","Jake","Jones","205-612-5519","30");
Record Employee5("Ab127","Jake","Jones","205-612-5519","30");
Record Employee6("Ab128","Jake","Jones","205-612-5519","30");
Record Employee7("Ab123","Jake","Jones","205-612-5519","30");
Record Employee8("Ab12310","Jake","Jones","205-612-5519","30");
Record Employee9("Ab1231","Jake","Jones","205-612-5519","30");
Record Employee10("Ab1232","Jake","Jones","205-612-5519","30");
Record Item[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Item[i].setemployeeID("NA");
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << Item[i].getemployeeID() << endl;
    cout << Employee1.getemployeeID() << endl;
    cout << Employee1.getfirstName() << endl;
    cout << Employee1.getlastName() << endl;
    cout << Employee1.gettelephone() << endl;
    cout << Employee1.getage() << endl;
    cout << Employee2.getemployeeID() << endl;
    cout << Employee2.getfirstName() << endl;
    cout << Employee2.getlastName() << endl;
    cout << Employee2.gettelephone() << endl;
    cout << Employee2.getage() << endl;
    cout << Employee3.getemployeeID() << endl;
    cout << Employee3.getfirstName() << endl;
    cout << Employee3.getlastName() << endl;
    cout << Employee3.gettelephone() << endl;
    cout << Employee3.getage() << endl;
    cout << Employee4.getemployeeID() << endl;
    cout << Employee4.getfirstName() << endl;
    cout << Employee4.getlastName() << endl;
    cout << Employee4.gettelephone() << endl;
    cout << Employee4.getage() << endl;
    cout << Employee5.getemployeeID() << endl;
    cout << Employee5.getfirstName() << endl;
    cout << Employee5.getlastName() << endl;
    cout << Employee5.gettelephone() << endl;
    cout << Employee5.getage() << endl;
    cout << Employee6.getemployeeID() << endl;
    cout << Employee6.getfirstName() << endl;
    cout << Employee6.getlastName() << endl;
    cout << Employee6.gettelephone() << endl;
    cout << Employee6.getage() << endl;
    cout << Employee7.getemployeeID() << endl;
    cout << Employee7.getfirstName() << endl;
    cout << Employee7.getlastName() << endl;
    cout << Employee7.gettelephone() << endl;
    cout << Employee7.getage() << endl;
    cout << Employee8.getemployeeID() << endl;
    cout << Employee8.getfirstName() << endl;
    cout << Employee8.getlastName() << endl;
    cout << Employee8.gettelephone() << endl;
    cout << Employee8.getage() << endl;
    cout << Employee9.getemployeeID() << endl;
    cout << Employee9.getfirstName() << endl;
    cout << Employee9.getlastName() << endl;
    cout << Employee9.gettelephone() << endl;
    cout << Employee9.getage() << endl;
    cout << Employee10.getemployeeID() << endl;
    cout << Employee10.getfirstName() << endl;
    cout << Employee10.getlastName() << endl;
    cout << Employee10.gettelephone() << endl;
    cout << Employee10.getage() << endl;

    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        cout <<("Employee ID:")<<endl;
        cin >> idIN;
        cout <<("First Name:")<<endl;
        cin >> fnameIN;
        cout <<("Last Name:")<<endl;
        cin >> lnameIN;
        cout <<("Telephone #:")<<endl;
        cin >> telephoneIN;
        cout <<("Age:")<<endl;
        cin >> ageIN;

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate clearly on the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Read up on scope. `Record Item[10];` is placed such that it only exists in case 1.

Comment: Back up your code and then remove everything that has nothing to do with your problem. This often makes it easier to spot the problem and when it doesn't, it makes it easier for one of us out here to spot the problem. For more information on this approach, read [mcve].

Comment: @KunalPuri Yes I will try. I am wanting to get the user to input fields into the record such as firstName, lastName and so on. I was trying to use the set methods I defined in my Record.h class to get the input from user then store it into fnameIN, lnameIN and so on. I then wanted to use the stored info in Case 1 and Case 2, so I could then display all the records with the ones inputted by the user. Does that help at all?

Comment: Where exactly did you face issue in this use case? Are you facing issue in getting input? Or you are facing issue in storing data? Or something else?

Comment: `Record Item[10];` needs to be moved in `int main()` before the loop. Although after that happens your indexing is wrong. valid indices are 0 .. 9 not 1..10

Comment: @drescherjm That helped me use the stored variable throughout all cases! I fixed the indexing. Thank you

Comment: @KunalPuri The problem is with storing the data. I need 10 records for each person, and I am wanting to use an array to store 5 different fields for 10 different people. Can I use an array to store multiple variables?

Comment: @KunalPuri I think I can be more specific. In my code where it has void setemployeeID (string idIn); Do I have to set this parameter prior to using the get method to display the value? Can I use cin to store a value to set and then use the get method to display it?

Comment: @JakeHuckestein I have tried to answer your question. Please pay special attention to suggestions.

Comment: Removed unnecessary words, formatted the code by removing unnecessary spaces and reformatte d the question to be more readable

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the question, You can do somewhat like this:

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Record.h"
#define RECORD_SIZE 10

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int choice;
    Record items[RECORD_SIZE];

    do {
        cout << "Menu\n";
        cout << "1.Input information into an record.\n";
        cout << "2.Display all information in all records.\n";
        cout << "3.Exit the program\n";
        cout << "Please enter your choice:\n";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice) {
            case 1: {
                std::string fnameIN, lnameIN, idIN, telephoneIN, ageIN;

                for (int i = 0; i < RECORD_SIZE; i++) {
                    cout << "Enter Employee ID:\n";
                    cin >> idIN;

                    cout << "Enter Employee's First Name:\n";
                    cin >> fnameIN;

                    cout << "Enter Employee's Last Name:'\n";
                    cin >> lnameIN;

                    cout << "Enter Employee's Phone Number':\n";
                    cin >> telephoneIN;

                    cout << "Enter Employee's Age:\n";
                    cin >> ageIN;

                    items[i].setemployeeID(idIN);
                    items[i].setfirstName(fnameIN);
                    items[i].setlastName(lnameIN);
                    items[i].settelephone(telephoneIN);
                    items[i].setage(ageIN);
                }

                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                for (int i = 0; i < RECORD_SIZE; i++) {
                    cout << "Employee " << (i + 1) << " details: \n"
                         << items[i].getemployeeID() << "\n"
                         << items[i].getfirstName() << "\n"
                         << items[i].getlastName() << "\n"
                         << items[i].gettelephone() << "\n"
                         << items[i].getage() << "\n";
                }
                getchar();

                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                break;
            }

            default: {
                cout << "Invalid Choice entered!";  
            }
        }
    } while (choice != 3);

    return 0;
}
```

**Suggestions:**

1) In Record class, you can make the getter functions as `const`. Like this:

```
string getfirstName() const;
```

2) In this case, You may use default arguments instead of defining a separate constructors. You may do something like this:

**Record.h**

```
#ifndef Record_h
#define Record_h

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Record
{
private:
    string employeeID;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string telephone;
    string age;

public:
    explicit Record(string idIn = "NA", string fnameIn = "NA", string lnameIn = "NA",
           string telephoneIn = "NA", string ageIn = "NA") {
        setemployeeID(idIn);
        setfirstName(fnameIn);
        setlastName(lnameIn);
        settelephone(telephoneIn);
        setage(ageIn);
    }

    void setemployeeID (string idIn);

    void setfirstName (string fnameIn);

    void setlastName (string lnameIn);

    void settelephone (string phoneIn);

    void setage (string ageIn);

    string getemployeeID() const;

    string getfirstName() const;

    string getlastName() const;

    string gettelephone() const;

    string getage() const;
};

#endif /* Record_hpp */
```

3) For validations, always use setters.

**Record.cpp**

```
#include "Record.h"

void Record::setemployeeID (string idIn) {
    employeeID = idIn;
}

void Record::setfirstName (string fnameIn) {
    firstName = fnameIn;
}

void Record::setlastName (string lnameIn) {
    lastName = lnameIn;
}

void Record::settelephone (string phoneIn) {
    // TODO: I would highly recommend you to do this using REGEX
    if (phoneIn.length() == 12
            && phoneIn.at(3) == '-'
            && phoneIn.at(7) == '-') {
        telephone = phoneIn;
    } else {
        telephone = "000-000-0000";
    }
}

void Record::setage (string ageIn) {
    age = ageIn;
}
//get functions
string Record::getemployeeID() const {
    return employeeID;
}

string Record::getfirstName() const {
    return firstName;
}

string Record::getlastName() const {
    return lastName;
}

string Record::gettelephone() const {
    return telephone;
}

string Record::getage() const {
    return age;
}
```

4) As I have mentioned in the code also, You should look to replace the `telephone` related validation with an alternative involving RegEx.

5) Use standard naming conventions for method names.